# Integral with Riemann Zeta Function. Trying to understand behavior

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-zeta

Hey Math Stack Exchange,

I have an integral that I'd like to try and simplify or get bounds on. It involves the Riemann Zeta function which I'm not super familiar with and so I thought I'd look for help here since you all have been helpful in the past. Thank you for taking a look at it and any help would be greatly appreciated!

$$f(x) = \Big(\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\Big)*\int_{c-i \infty}^{c + i \infty} \frac{x^w}{w}*\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta^k(w)}{k} dw$$

where $c=2\gamma -1$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler Mascheroni Constant.

There are a couple of things I'm trying to understand about it:

1) Is there a simplified form or an identity?

2) Is there a lower bound or upper bound behavior to it? (i.e. Big-O or Little-O)?

3) What happens to this as we take the limit of x going to infinity?

Thank you guys again for taking a look at it!

Comment: I probably won't be able to help, but I am curious about the context where you found this integral.

Comment: I'd also be interested in seeing where this comes from.  One issue I can see is that the sum on the interior is generally not convergent.

Comment: What is $i\infty$ ?

Comment: Is it proven that is the integral is convergent? If to take one summand with $k=2$ and put $x=1$ seems to  diverge.